# cloud composer + cloud ml engine tutorial?

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

i couldnt find tutorial for cloud ML engine + airflow, someone please help deploy a cloud ml engine model and orchestrate with airflow to run training with new data every hour

Answer (score 4):

You can schedule ML Engine jobs using the Composer quick start available [here](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/quickstart) and the Airflow ML Engine operators' documentation [here](https://airflow.apache.org/integration.html#cloud-ml-engine). The model package gets created on GCS when you train a job on MLEngine or it can even be created manually. If you intend to do hyper parameter optimization then your package will need to contain a setup.py as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/packaging-trainer).

Below is an example of the DAG for iris scikit model ([reference here](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/scikit/getting-started-training))-

```
with models.DAG(
        'composer_sample_ml',
        # Continue to run DAG once per day
        schedule_interval=datetime.timedelta(days=1),
        default_args=default_dag_args) as dag:

    train_model = mlengine_operator.MLEngineTrainingOperator(
        task_id='train_model',
        project_id='PROJECT_ID',
        job_id='{}_{}'.format('iris_train_job', str(uuid.uuid4())),
        package_uris='gs://BUCKET_ID/scikit_learn_job_dir/packages/PACKAGE_ID/iris_sklearn_trainer-0.1.tar.gz',
        training_python_module='iris_sklearn_trainer.iris',
        training_args=["--jobDir='gs://BUCKET_ID/scikit_learn_job_dir'"],
        region='us-central1',
        scale_tier='BASIC',
        runtimeVersion = '1.8',
        pythonVersion = '2.7'
    )

    train_model
```

Comment: I have a doubt about the hyperparameter tuning.  When i use the python api, I put the hp_spec as a part of the json. In this case is not clear to me how to pass all that specs

Comment: @PabloV. Have you tried packaging the training task similar to iris sample [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/tree/master/tensorflow/standard/iris)? Essentially the HP spec goes in the hptuning_config.yaml and the package should have setup.py for it to be picked up.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a tutorial that includes ML Engine and Composer: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/machine-learning/recommendation-system-tensorflow-deploy

Answer (score 0):

As an update for anyone who may be looking post-June 2020, in addition to the resources above, these two PRs include updates to the example DAG and a guide for these operators. I don't think they're updated in the docs yet, but once it is I'll try to update

1. https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/9727
2. https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/9798/files?short_path=b8207cb#diff-b8207cb1601efda85d3cbcf0087a6347